# Rails + Delayed Job => email view template does not get updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, delayed-job

I'm using Rails + Delayed Job for my app. Everytime I update my email view, the server/delayed job does not pick it up.

Who's doing the caching? Rails or Delayed Job? any idea how to fix it?..

Other info:
- I tried restarting delayed job and it still does not help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old version of the worker might be running the job. Make sure all instances of delayed_job are killed before starting it.

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Might take sometime for me to try it because it only happen on production..

Comment: I usually `ps -ef| grep delayed_job` before and after every deploy - it seems to be notorious for not shutting down old instances cleanly.

Comment: You're right Julian, thanks! I have a script to stop delayed job everytime I deploy. I thought that should be ok. But using ps -ef I saw an instances that was up since April! killed it and it fix all the problem. Thanks again!