# Clear worker cache in delayed jobs in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using [delayed jobs](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) in my rails application. it works fine but there is an issue occurred on production server. I created a class in lib and call its method from controller to generate a csv file through delayed jobs. It was working fine when I ran the delayed jobs on local and production server but then I made some changes to this class for file naming convention and restarted the delayed jobs on local and then on production server. Now when I call that method through delayed job then it works according to latest changes I made to the class and sometimes it uses the old logic of file naming convention.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Delayed job has a hidden "feature" which is to ignore any changes to your app, and just use old settings, env-variables, email-templates, etc.  You can clear every cache and restart your server, and it still holds onto data which no longer exists anywhere in your app's codebase.

[delayed_job - Performs not up to date code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971315/delayed-job-performs-not-up-to-date-code)

Also be aware that DJ's "restart" does not always kill and restart all the workers, so you need to hunt them down and kill them all manually with

```
ps aux | grep delay
```

See: [Rails + Delayed Job => email view template does not get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819609/rails-delayed-job-email-view-template-does-not-get-updated)

I have not yet found a "clear delayed job cache" function.  If it exists, someone please post it here.

Comment: Thank you, @JosephK.  Do you know where this old code is stored?  Is it stored in Redis, and if so, is the solution to wipe the Redis database clean?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just spent almost 4 hours trying everything to delete failing `delayed_jobs` in **Heroku**. In case you get here trying to kill a zombie `delayed_job`, but you're **in Heroku, this won't work**.

You can not do `ps aux` like you'd do in a regular server, nor you can do `rake jobs:clear`, and if you check via Rails console, you'll see the jobs there, but not in the Database, so nothing you can do there either.

What I did was placing the app in maintenance mode, made a deployment totally uninstalling `delayed_job` gem and all its references, and then another deployment reverting that change. That cleared the zombie cache, and that did the trick.

Comment: Thank you, @unmultimedio, I am using Heroku too and experiencing this problem. Do you know where this old code is stored? I tried your solution of removing the gem and reinstalling it, but somehow the old code is still running.

Is it stored in Redis, and if so, is the solution to wipe the Redis database clean?  `redis-stats-reset` did not clear it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Dokku. My solution was to remove the `worker=1` entry from my DOKKU_SCALE file (so all it contained was `web=1`) and also to remove the `worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work` line from my Procfile.

I pushed that to my production server, reversed the changes above, pushed again and it was fixed.